# How to solve error installing io package in octave?

Tags: io, octave

I did the same steps as in the video but after pkg install( [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILhVbr5bEV0)) I get :
'error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 2
tar: "/C/Users/D\303\263ri/Desktop/Octave/io-2.6.3.tar.gz": Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: called from
unpack at line 279 column 5
untar at line 48 column 5
install at line 93 column 9
pkg at line 568 column 9'

[image]

Comment: What is your setup, what exactly did you do, and what is error message, please format the output properly.  `/C/Users` is a very strange beginning of a path string.  A string that mixes linux slashes `/` and windows ones `\` is not a correct path either.

Comment: I have version 6.2.0

Comment: Non-English characters in the username could be the reason

Comment: @Dimitry: That path is actually kind of normal: the `/C/Users` is a way for referencing the Windows C: drive in the Linux compatibility layer that Octave ships with. And it's not mixing Unix forward slashes and Windows backslashes: those forward slashes are the actual file separators, and the backslashes are escape sequences for the Unicode-encoded "Dóri" username, which contains non-ASCII characters. (Plus it's actually fine to use Unix-style forward slashes on Windows!)

Comment: Yes, by now I've figured as much. At the moment of the comment however, the question didn't have the image with username attached. Neither it was stated if it was wsl, mingw or native version of the program. (Guess that's apparent by now.)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. BTW, I'm pretty sure there is no "native" version of Octave for Windows; this way (using MXE and mingw) is the only way it comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be a bug in Octave related to how it is handling the encoding of non-ASCII Unicode characters in your "Dóri" username, which occurs in the path to your Desktop directory. Please drop by the Octave Discourse at https://octave.discourse.group/ and report this as a bug, and we will help you out. (This would be an interesting bug to work on, as there is ongoing conversation in the Octave maintainers group about how to handle Unicode string representation.)

In the mean time, you can maybe get this to work by doing a Forge-based installation of the io package with `pkg install -forge io` instead.